# Implementation of the divide-and-conquer principle for a specific summation formula

Tags: recursion, divide-and-conquer, fast-fourier-transform

I have found two formulas in the [work](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf) on pages 5 and 6, of which I am trying to develop a recursive implementation. The similarity to the DFT or FFT might be useful here. I divide this question into three sections, in the first part I explain my thoughts, in the second section there are open questions and in the third part I will present some codes.

**The most important question first**, (for those who want to know quickly what it's all about without having to read my thoughts first): How are the formulas (see below) (1) and (2) implemented recursively? I have made a first suggestion in this question, it is possible that I am wrong.

**Update**: I added a reference implementation.

---

### Section 1: Ideas/Reasoning

I will give the formulas below and then describe an approach that I think might help to implement the formulas recursively.

First of all

$$\hat{f}_{2i} = \sum_{j=0}^{127} f_{2j} \xi^{(2 br_7(i) +1) j}, \quad i=0,1,...,127 \qquad  Eq. \, (1)$$
$$\hat{f}_{2i+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{127} f_{2j+1} \xi^{(2 br_7(i) +1) j}, \quad i=0,1,...,127 \qquad  Eq. \, (2)$$

where $br_7(i)$ stands for a function that we can consider as given and reverses a 7-bit value $i$, e.g. $1_{10} = 0000001_2 \rightarrow 1000000_2 = 64_{10}$. The $\xi$ is a 256th primitive root and it is $\xi = 17$. For more details, please refer to the [paper](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf) (pages 5 and 6).

For a recursive implementation, I have considered the following for the first sum:

$$\hat{f}_{2i} = \sum_{j=0}^{127} f_{2j} \cdot \xi^{(2 br_{7}(i)+1)j} = \sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)2j} + \sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j+2} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)(2j+1)} $$
$$= \sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)2j} + \xi^{2br_{7}(i)+1}\sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j+2} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)2j} \qquad  Eq. \, (3)$$

also applies due to the periodicity:

$$\hat{f}_{2i + N/2} = \sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)2j} - \xi^{2br_{7}(i)+1}\sum_{j=0}^{63} f_{4j+2} \xi^{(2br_{7}(i)+1)2j} \qquad  Eq. \, (4)$$

So now we have two separate sums that also halve the input size in each step. This is very similar to a divide-and-conquer approach. Overall, this is very similar to the FFT.

Inspired by the FFT algorithm, a recursive version could look something like this (I think):

[image]

Here I would like to note that the input $a$ is an array that contains the even indices and is already reduced to half size. The idea is $f$ consists of all values. For $\hat{f}_{2i}$ we only need the even coefficients $f_{2i}$. If we split the even coefficients further into even and "odd", this corresponds roughly to what formulas 3 and 4 express. So if $f = (f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4,...f_{255})$ then $a = (f'_0=f_0, f'_1 = f_2, f'_2 = f_4, f'_3=f_6, ..., f'_{127}=f_{254})$, so $f_{4j}$ becomes $f'_{2j'}$ and $f_{4j+2}$ becomes $f'_{2j'+1}$, where $j'=0,1,...,64$.

As a verification, I have created a non-recursive iterative implementation of the expression of the formula $\hat{f}_{2i} = \sum_{j=0}^{127} f_{2j} \xi^{(2 br_7(i) +1) j}, \quad i=0,1,...,127$, using two for loops to verify the correctness.

---

### Section 2: Questions

I now come to my comments and questions. First of all, I have to report that as soon as you omit the function $br_7(i)$ and only calculate with $i$, both the recursive implementation and the non-recursive version (these are two for loops that calculate $\hat{f}_{2i}$) output the same values, I have checked this with some examples. However, if I include the $br_7(i)$ in both implementations, the outputs differ! This is the reason for my first question.

My first question: Why does the introduction of $br_7(i)$ in the recursive version change the output compared to the non-recursive version which also uses $br_7(i)$? For your information: I have implemented the $br_{7}(i)$ using an array that contains the corresponding values.

A second fundamental question is whether I have implemented the formulas (3) and (4), which I have converted and adapted, correctly in the notation?

Probably the most important question in a nutshell: How are the formulas (1) and (2) implemented recursively? I have made a first suggestion in this question, it is possible that I am wrong.

---

### Section 3: Code

Below I have given an example implementation that realizes the formula from equation 1 in a simple iterative way and a recursive variant.

I would like to note two important things. Firstly, I have adapted the formula from equation 1 for the recursive version so that I can work directly with an array of size 128 that consists only of the $f_{2i}$ elements. The iterative version uses an array of size 256, where only the even indices are filled.

Now we come to the part that is really exciting. In the code you can see a conversion of
$$\hat{f}_{2i} = \sum_{j=0}^{127} f_{2j} \xi^{(2 i +1) j} \pmod{3329}, \quad i=0,1,...,127 \qquad Eq. \, (1')$$
in iterative and recursive version. The interesting thing is that both functions give the same output, which shows that the recursive version seems to work. You can test this by running the program once, perhaps adding a few more values or modifying some. But my test cases have so far always delivered the same matching result.

The problem is the implementation of the actual formula with the bitreverse operation. Here the outputs of the iterative and recursive implementation differ, which indicates an error that I cannot find. An execution with the bitreverse operation leads to a replacement of `i` to `br[i]` in the iterative implementation in the second for loop at the power and in the recursive implementation `2*k+1` is replaced by `2*br[k]+1`. This is also stored in the appropriate place in the code. The question is why there are different results here.

```
    public class Dev{

    // bit reverse values
    public static int[] br = {0, 64, 32, 96, 16, 80, 48, 112, 8, 72, 40, 104, 
        24, 88, 56, 120, 4, 68, 36, 100, 20, 84, 52, 116, 12, 76, 44, 108, 
        28, 92, 60, 124, 2, 66, 34, 98, 18, 82, 50, 114, 10, 74, 42, 106, 26, 
        90, 58, 122, 6, 70, 38, 102, 22, 86, 54, 118, 14, 78, 46, 110, 30, 
        94, 62, 126, 1, 65, 33, 97, 17, 81, 49, 113, 9, 73, 41, 105, 25, 89, 
        57, 121, 5, 69, 37, 101, 21, 85, 53, 117, 13, 77, 45, 109, 29, 93, 
        61, 125, 3, 67, 35, 99, 19, 83, 51, 115, 11, 75, 43, 107, 27, 91, 59, 
        123, 7, 71, 39, 103, 23, 87, 55, 119, 15, 79, 47, 111, 31, 95, 63, 127};
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        // Test values for iterative call
        int[] a = new int[256];
        a[0] = 1;
        a[2] = 2;
        a[4] = 3;
        a[128] = 9;
        a[144] = 42;
        a[164] = 10;
        a[254] = 4;        
        int[] res = function(a, 256, 17);
        
        // Test values for recursive call
        int[] b = new int[128];
        b[0] = 1;
        b[2/2] = 2;
        b[4/2] = 3;
        b[128/2] = 9;
        b[144/2] = 42;
        b[164/2] = 10;
        b[254/2] = 4;
        int[] res_rec = function_recursive(b, 128, 17);
        
        // Print the results
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length/2; i++){
            System.out.print(res[2 * i] + ", ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        // For readability negative values 
        for(int i = 0; i < res_rec.length; i++){
            if(res_rec[i] < 0 ){
                res_rec[i] = res_rec[i] + 3329;
            }
            System.out.print(res_rec[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
    
    // Iterative calculation of hat{f}_{2i}
    public static int[] function(int[] a, int n, int zeta){
        int[] y = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++){
                int power = (2 * i + 1) * j;    // replace i with br[i]
                y[2 * i] += a[2 * j] * pow(zeta, power, 3329) % 3329;
                y[2 * i] = y[2 * i] % 3329;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }
    
    // Recursive calculation of hat{f}_{2i}
    public static int[] function_recursive(int[] a, int n, int zeta){
        if (n == 1){
            int[] tmp = new int[1];
            tmp[0] = a[0];
            return tmp;
        }

        int[] even = new int[n / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
            even[i] = a[2 * i];
        }

        int[] odd = new int[n / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
            odd[i] = a[2 * i + 1];
        }

        int[] E = function_recursive(even, n / 2, pow(zeta, 2 , 3329));
        int[] O = function_recursive(odd, n / 2,  pow(zeta, 2 , 3329));

        int[] y = new int[n];

        for (int k = 0; k < n / 2; k++){
            y[k]            = (E[k] + (O[k] * pow(zeta, 2*k+1 , 3329))) % 3329; // replace 2*k+1 with 2*br[k]+1
            y[k + n / 2]    = (E[k] - (O[k] * pow(zeta, 2*k+1 , 3329))) % 3329; // replace 2*k+1 with 2*br[k]+1
        }
        return y;
    }
    
    public static int pow(int a, int b, int c){
        long x=1;
        long y=a;
        while(b > 0){
            if(b%2 == 1){
                x = (x*y)%c;
            }
            y = (y*y)%c;
            b /= 2;
        }
        return (int) x%c;
    }
}
```